# Fiberglass tub bottom lip removal

Tags: bathroom, bathtub, ceramic-tile

I’m trying to install new tile on my bathroom floor (previously vinyl) without ripping out/damaging the existing tub. I realized however that once I’m done leveling the concrete subfloor and applying mortar etc. the tile will be above this lip (don’t know what this one is called in the image) and will become a water trap. I’m having trouble removing it as it seems firmly attached to the tub.

What would you recommend I do here? Rip out the tub? Can I save the tub while still installing tile? What is this bottom edge attached to the tub?

House was built in 90s and hasn’t been updated since.

Anything is helpful!

[image][image]

Comment: What have you tried so far, as for your attempts to remove that strip? It looks like it is a different color than the tub, is this an illusion due to lighting, or is it different from the tub finish? I ask because it looks like a trim piece for the previous vinyl floor, rather than a trim piece that came with the tub, if you can confirm this then I would recommend more forceful attempts to remove it.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like a separately applied piece, not something molded into the tub, but it's probably glued to the tub.

I'd call it cove molding.

A thin blade like a puttyknife driven into the joint (flex it so the blade is as parallel to the side of the tub as possible) should pop it off - there may be damage, depending on the glue job, but the damage should end up concealed if you glue it (or something else) back on, higher.

*Note that if an alleged puttyknife won't flex, it's not really a puttyknife, and in any case too thick - find a thinner one that will flex.*

Comment: Yeah something like a razor scraper, maybe?